# How can I display the field of the current page in a block twig template

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In my `Basic page` content type I have an image field called `sidebar_image`.

I have placed a block to my header region called `header_block` which is using a custom twig template. I'm wondering how I can get the `Basic page sidebar_image` to be displayed in my `header_block` twig template:

```
<h1>Some header</h1>
<img src="{{ sidebar_image }}" />
```

and in the preprocess function:

```
THEME_preprocess_block__header_block {
  $variables['sidebar_image'] = // get current pages sidebar image URL
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to load current page (node) like this:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
  // You can get nid and anything else you need from the node object.
  $nid = $node->id();
}
```

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145823/how-do-i-get-the-current-node-id

And then should be possible to access field value like:

```
$node->get('field_sidebar_image')->getValue();
```

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144947/how-do-i-access-a-field-value-for-an-entity-e-g-node-object

Just add some checking if your node is in specific content type and similar.

Comment: thank you this helped. Although `$node->get('field_sidebar_image')->getValue();` didn't work for me. I ended up passing the node to the twig view and doing: `{{ file_url(node.field_sidebar_image.entity.uri.value) }}`.